# Remove the leading 0's till the decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to remove the leading zeros in the decimal numbers.

So i want the output should be 
    `.324`
not
`0.324`. 
I tried `str.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");` Didn't work and i also tried the regex! 
No results!
And yes I am working with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^0\\.", ".");
```

Comment: can be shorter when using replaceFirst, which allows for a regex parameter: `str.replaceFirst("^0.", ".");`

Comment: Hm I meant there is no need for the whole if-then-else construct. `str.replaceFirst("^0.", ".");` is completely sufficient because `^0.` only replaces `0.` when `str` is starting with `0.` and not for example with `10.`

Comment: That's better. Thanks again.

Comment: It Worked! But still getting an error as the numbers are bigdecimals so on converting to string the result is of the exponential form!

Comment: how are you converting it to string?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava: Now that you're using a regex instead of a literal string, you have to escape the dot to remove its special meaning: (`"\\."`).

Comment: @Alan: You're absolutely correct. Correcting it. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to format `BigDecimal` having value `0.324` to `.324`. Then below works

```
    BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("0.23");// this will replace with your BigDecimal
    DecimalFormat df=null;
    //check if number is a fraction
    if(bd.remainder(BigDecimal.TEN).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)>0)
      df=new DecimalFormat(".###");
    else
      df=new DecimalFormat("##");

    System.out.print(df.format(bd));// .format returns string as .23

0.23->.23
0->0
90->90
80.12->80.12
```

Comment: It then adds .0 to non-decimals!
for e.g,
90 becomes 90.0
and 0 becomes .0
@Amit.rk3

Comment: @VishalSaini You can't have different formatting for same variable based on it's value. That is something which you have to handle in code, which is pretty easy. If I understand your requirement, you need this format only for decimals between 0 to 1. You can add simple if condition in your code to check if your value is lesser than one by `value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE)` . Then you can use above format, else use whatever is your existing format for other numbers greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Actually Sir! The numbers are greater than one! 
for e.g,
96.6
324.44
So i have to sort these numbers and then print in the sorted way! With decimals as .45 or .###

Answer (score 0):

do you want this for printing purposes? you wont be able to do any math using this, so i guess yes. then you could do:

```
BigDecimal number =new BigDecimal(0.254); 
       System.out.println(number.toString().substring(number.toString().indexOf("0.")+1));
```

output

> .254000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625

Comment: This will end up in a false result for some numbers. For example 1.24 will result in .24 as well.

Comment: so true! updated answer, even thought it is getting messy now:)